# Connection between number of partitions and number of surjections

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition

Let $P_n^m$ be the number of ways in which a set of $m$ elements can be partitioned into disjoint sets of $n$ elements, and $S_n^m$ be the number of surjections from a set of $m$ elements to a set of $n$ elements. I am trying to prove that $S_n^m=n!P_n^m$.

As a hint, I am given the fact that for any surjective function $f:X\to Y$, $\left\{f^{-1}(y)|y\in Y\right\}$  is a partition of $X$ in $n$ sets. This seems valid, since the sets are disjoint(otherwise $f$ wouldn't be single valued), and their union is $X$ because $f$ is defined on $X$.

With that in mind, it would be enough to show that every partition is "generated" by $n!$ functions, but I can't seem to be able to prove that. Any help/hints is appreciated!

Comment: Given a partition, number the parts and send each element to the number of the part it is in. How many ways do you have of numbering the parts?

Comment: Oh, and since there are $n!$ ways to number the parts, we have $n!$ functions. Nice! Thank you very much!